# It is not displaying the records of the database in RecyclerView. PHP codes are ok they are creating the jsons perfectly

Tags: php, android, android-recyclerview, android-volley

Records of Database are not being displayed as output. There is no output. Android Studio is not generating any kind of error.

MainActivity.java

```
package app.project.wedding.test3;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

List<PersonUtils> personUtilsList;

RequestQueue rq;

String request_url = "http://localhost/test/test3.php";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycleViewContainer);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    personUtilsList = new ArrayList<>();

    sendRequest();

}


public void sendRequest(){

    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, request_url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            for(int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++){

                PersonUtils personUtils = new PersonUtils();

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);

                    personUtils.setPersonFirstName(jsonObject.getString("firstname"));
                    personUtils.setPersonLastName(jsonObject.getString("lastname"));
                    personUtils.setJobProfile(jsonObject.getString("jobprofile"));

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                personUtilsList.add(personUtils);

            }

            mAdapter = new CustomRecyclerAdapter(MainActivity.this, personUtilsList);

            recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Volley Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    rq.add(jsonArrayRequest);

}
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
package app.project.wedding.test3;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;


public class CustomRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<PersonUtils> personUtils;

public CustomRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List personUtils) {
    this.context = context;
    this.personUtils = personUtils;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_list_item, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.itemView.setTag(personUtils.get(position));

    PersonUtils pu = personUtils.get(position);

    holder.pName.setText(pu.getPersonFirstName()+" "+pu.getPersonLastName());
    holder.pJobProfile.setText(pu.getJobProfile());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return personUtils.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView pName;
    public TextView pJobProfile;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        pName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pNametxt);
        pJobProfile = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pJobProfiletxt);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                PersonUtils cpu = (PersonUtils) view.getTag();

                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), cpu.getPersonFirstName()+" "+cpu.getPersonLastName()+" is "+ cpu.getJobProfile(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

    }
}
```

PersonUtils.java

```
package app.project.wedding.test3;

public class PersonUtils {

private String personFirstName;
private String personLastName;
private String jobProfile;

public String getPersonFirstName() {
    return personFirstName;
}

public void setPersonFirstName(String personFirstName) {
    this.personFirstName = personFirstName;
}

public String getPersonLastName() {
    return personLastName;
}

public void setPersonLastName(String personLastName) {
    this.personLastName = personLastName;
}

public String getJobProfile() {
    return jobProfile;
}

public void setJobProfile(String jobProfile) {
    this.jobProfile = jobProfile;
}
```

test3.php

```
<?php

    $server="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="root";
    $db="userinfo";

    $conn = mysqli_connect($server,$username,$password,$db);
    if(!$conn)
    {
        echo "Not Connected";
    }

    $sql="select * from test3;";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $response=array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        array_push($response,array("firstname"=>$row["firstname"],"lastname"=>$row["lastname"],"jobprofile"=>$row["jobprofile"]));
    }
    echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code review service. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

USE Request.Method.GET for data get.
public void sendRequest(){

```
JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, request_url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

        for(int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++){

            PersonUtils personUtils = new PersonUtils();

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);

                personUtils.setPersonFirstName(jsonObject.getString("firstname"));
                personUtils.setPersonLastName(jsonObject.getString("lastname"));
                personUtils.setJobProfile(jsonObject.getString("jobprofile"));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            personUtilsList.add(personUtils);

        }

        mAdapter = new CustomRecyclerAdapter(MainActivity.this, personUtilsList);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Volley Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        error.printStackTrace();
    }
});

rq.add(jsonArrayRequest);
```

}

Comment: yes i have tried that, still theres no output on the screen

Comment: first of all check the url in manually in postman if data come then the issue is network because it is work only in same network.so connect your device in same network.